# MSMQ Outgoing queues "Connected" indefinitely

Tags: .net, msmq, nservicebus

Is there a way to keep MSMQ outgoing queues on a server in state "Connected" indefinitely?

Note: Windows 2008 R2 Server, up to ~200 outgoing queues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you can do is set CleanupInterval to 0xFFFFFFFF (which is 50 days, I think) and increase the thread pool with QMThreadNo to cover the number of outgoing queues.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957466.aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779929(v=WS.10).aspx.

[How to help outgoing queues scale in MSMQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2009/09/07/how-to-help-outgoing-queues-scale-in-msmq.aspx)

Cheers
John Breakwell

Comment: thanks for your response John. What would you propose a decent value for the QMThreadNO for a server that will be handling ~200 clients.

Comment: Threads aren't free so I would recommend setting QMThreadNo as low as you can whilst providing the performance you need. Only experimentation will let you know the optimum value.